# Azure: Unable to find the resource (app insights) when creating a deployment

Tags: azure, teamcity, azure-cli

When running a build in TeamCity, we run some azure scripts. But occasionally I get the error about unable to find the resource (application insights).
The error is:

```
ERROR: Deployment failed. Correlation ID: ############. {
"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "Unable to find the resource /subscriptions/###########/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/myAppInsight, please confirm that it exists."
```

}

The script we use is:

```
az extension add -n application-insights
az monitor app-insights component create --app $functionAppName --location $location --resource-group $rgTelemetryConfig --tags $tags

az functionapp create -n $functionAppName -g $rgTelemetryConfig --app-insights $functionAppName --storage-account $storageAccount --consumption-plan-location $location --tags $tags --runtime $runtime
az group deployment create --resource-group $rgTelemetryConfig --template-file ./templates/monitoring/config-template.json --parameters appInsights=$functionAppName
```

In the arm template, we do refer to the appInsights severl times, like:

```
"actionGroupId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroup'))]"
"scopes": [
                "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsights'))]"
            ]
"componentId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsights'))]"
```

Does anyone know how I should fix it?

Comment: Could you provide the arm template?

Comment: @JoyWang In the template, we do refer to appInsights several times. Do you think it might cause the issue? I added some of the pieces in the template where we use it to the question

Comment: Try some judgement statement like `while do`, I am not familiar with bash, could not help you any more.:-)

Comment: I did try some invoke-retry, it doesn't help either.. I am kind of stuck.
What I have tried so far: add sleep, use retry invoke, update azure cli, use azure powershell. 
I hope someone has experienced a similar issue and got it fixed, and share the solution.

Comment: @JoyWang thanks for pointing me to the right direction